# Robolectric 3.0 custom AndroidManifest.xml in @Config properties ignored

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm writing an Android Library in android Studio 1.5.1.
I've followed the normal creation flow in order to create the Android Library as explained here: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/

In order to test some library's internal classes I've added Robolectric 3.0. 
The default AndroidManifest.xml is in: 
`./mylib/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
path, moreover I've added a customized AndroidManifest.xml file in path `./mylib/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml` and in my test class (in `./mylib/src/test/java/com/../MyTestClass.java`)
I've added this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "./src/test/AndroidManifest.xml")
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyTestClass {
...
}
```

However at runtime Robolectric seems to ignore the 'manifest' property and take always the AndroidManifest.xml in `./mylib/src/main/` directory.

The Working Directory in the test configuration is correctly configured:

[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is so special in your manifest?

Comment: I need a testing and building flow for this library and the manifest that should be packaged in the resulting *.aar file and should be minimal, BUT third app that integrates my library must include (in its manifest) some meta-data (the value are obviously app's specific)  and permissions. 
I need to test the library behaviour as well as in  real environment.

Comment: I don't get, you want to test that android build tools are building your project correctly? Or you want to test that manifest of the library contains specific metadata? Or you want to check that android passes metadata from manifest to library?

Comment: I want to check that manifest from the app, that includes my library has the correct metadata, but these tests actually running in the library scope.
I use a fake manifest, which should replicate the one from the app in order to do that. 
So I need to pass this fake manifest to my test with`@Config(manifest=...)` property

Comment: You just said that it is not the real test, you testing some manifest which is not coming nor from your library, nor from app that integrates it. Also, as for me, you're  testing Android build tools which I don't recommend to do. I would just check that manifest of your library has metadata, and it will be not robolectric test but test that reads xml and checks values